# DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND Failed to find data source: mlflow-experiment. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am trying to load MLflow experiement run data on databricks using Python as suggested in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/mlflow-experiment).
But when I try to do the same, I am getting error "**org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find data source: mlflow-experiment. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html**".

Please help me resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJuhn.png)

I have checked the experiment id and found it correct.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is `Databricks Runtime 6.0 ML or above.`

So, create a cluster having above requirement.

[image]

Then run your code with experiment id.

```
df = spark.read.format("mlflow-experiment").load("1036690367521372")
display(df)
```

[image]